# How to retrieve truncated queries from sys.`statements_with_temp_tables` view?

Tags: mysql, performance, schema

I am running below query on MySQL 5.7.22 and I see that queries are truncated under query column of the table.

```
select * from sys.`statements_with_temp_tables` 
where db = 'schema_name'
order by memory_tmp_tables desc;
```

Is there any way we can retrieve these queries in full?

Comment: I am running the query on Mysql workbench 8.0. I tried retrieving the value using "open value in viewer" as well. I think this value is actually truncated.

Comment: Try using the slowlog instead.  I don't think they are truncated there (at least when using `FILE`).

Comment: A trick that _might_ work is to embed comments near the beginning of any lengthy queries - this will at least help you find the source of the query.

Comment: @RickJames I am running, above mentioned analysis query on production mysql rds instance with a lot of app servers sending queries to it. My goal is to find out queries which were creating temporary tables which were promoted to disk. Apparently, I cannot ask them to add comments to the existing queries to find out a single query.

Comment: @RickJames how do we find memory temp tables promoted to disk temp tables from slow running queries?

Comment: Temp tables lead to slowness lead to showing up in the slowlog.  The "worst" queries in the slowlog (according to pt-query-digest) are the most important to worry about speeding up.  Sometimes temp tables are necessary; it is just one of several symptoms.

Answer (score 3):

I have been enoyed by this query truncation for a long time too. So I just finished a short research to finally get a solution...
So. This 'truncation' is controlled by *@sys.statement_truncate_len* option. You can set it to reasonably long value before you select from *sys.statements_with_temp_tables* (or any other table containing monitoring data):

```
SET @sys.statement_truncate_len = 1000;
select * from sys.`statements_with_temp_tables`;
```

You can read more on this in official doc:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-sys-config.html

P.S. If you use MySql Workbench: do not forget to set 'Max.Field Value Length to display' limit in Edit - Preferences - SQL Execution (main menu)